# Variable PMW generator using Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, pwm, circuit-design, verilog

I've made a code in Verilog for a variable duty-cycle digitally controlled PWM generator. I will be using it in a system I am designing for controlling a buck-boost converter that will regulate the voltage of big solar panel.

My code works fine in simulations and here it's:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module PWM_gen(
    input clk,
    input [7:0] duty,
    output sig
    );

    reg [7:0] count = 8'b00000000;
    reg signal;
    wire [7:0] threshold;
    assign threshold = duty;



    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
    count <= count + 8'b00000001;
    assign signal = (threshold >= count);
    end
    assign sig = signal;
endmodule
```

The frequency of the PWM signal is

$$f = f_{clk}/2^N$$

where **N** is the size of the count register in bits. The duty cycle can be set by the `duty` input bus, if 50% duty cycle is required, `duty` must be set to `7F` and so on.

The problem is, although it's working is it the correct implementation? I found a [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e79d/d2f908be5a4457ef1cfaa1467dd50a4c574b.pdf) specifying different methods and designs of digital PWM generation circuits, the problem is should I follow those methods? what is usually used in the industry and what are the drawbacks of this implementation, I feel that it's very simple.

Comment: This is not really an application where a programmable logic device makes sense - typically you would use an MCU timer.  Your question is really too broad to be answerable, but 1) You should really register the duty cycle in the same clock domain so it does not change mid comparison (the actual issue is more complex) and 2) in some FPGA technologies you may need an explicit reset to initially start things off

Comment: @ChrisStratton 1)you mean inside the `always` block? 2) Yeah I am aware of that, I still haven't put it into the board yet. As to why I am using aN FPGA, I don't know. I am aware that microcontrollers could be better suited to this application but I wanted to see if I could build most of the control system on a single chip.

Comment: An MCU *is* a single chip solution given the timer peripherals.  "I don't know" is a plausible reason to *experiment* with an FPGA for learning but not a reason to *deploy* one where it is misfit.

Comment: The question isn't really about the details of generating a PWM signal, it's actually about picking the correct duty cycle to generate. You haven't told us anything at all about how you're doing that, or how this PWM signal is actually used in the system.

Comment: @DaveTweed No that's not my question, sorry if I didn't word it correctly. I was asking about the correct implementation of the PMW generator and if I need to use a better approach. The correct duty cycle is irrelevant here since it will be changed to regulate the PV voltage.

Comment: You already stated that it works. What else would you want a different implementation to do?

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes you are right, I am doing this to learn, I got a long spring break and the labs are open during this time so I am experimenting.

Comment: You can ignore @ChrisStratton. There's absolutely nothing wrong with doing this in an FPGA -- it just isn't what he's used to seeing. You can even put a CPU in your FPGA if you need it.

Comment: @DaveTweed I wanted to see if it was wrong or had problems I couldn't see

Comment: @DaveTweed - sure, you *can* put it in an FPGA, but as you just pointed out yourself, you'll probably end up building a soft core CPU for that *algorithm* you were hinting at.  Been there and done that, *when there was a justification to*. 
 Most MCU's are a lot easier to integrate on a board than an FPGA, and faster to develop for.   There's nothing here that points towards the hassle of an FPGA being warranted for an actually deployed solution; it makes more sense to do FPGA learning projects on problems that model real FPGA applications.

Comment: @ChrisStratton as I stated before, I just wanted to know if I can do it or not, implementing this on an MCU is less of a hassle I agree, but it's a good learning experience for me, and as you said it's an odd aplication of FPGAs which is fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I would say about your PWM implementation is that it is way too wordy, with unnecessary signals. Here's a much more compact representation of exactly the same thing:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module PWM_gen (
    input       clk,
    input [7:0] duty,
    output      sig
);
    reg [7:0] count = 8'b00000000;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
      count <= count + 8'b00000001;
    end

    assign sig = (duty >= count);
endmodule
```

Comment: The problem is I am always afraid of not using extra stuff because if an error occurs I will be lost and won't be able to fix it, I don't even know where to start with troubleshooting since Vivado doesn't always show why you were wrong with something. Thanks, I have learned a lot from the code above because I discovered that some stuff I knew was wrong.